# Xcode 12.2 Secure Password Text Field undesired behavior

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield

I created a signUp view controller with 3 textFields for the email, username and password. Here is the entire view controller file:

```
//
//  SignupViewController.swift
//  bounce_frontend
//
//  Created by Sebastian Fay on 11/21/20.
//

import UIKit

class SignupViewController: UIViewController {
    
    struct Constants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5.0
    }
    
    private let emailField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Email"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel.cgColor
        return field
    }()
    
    private let usernameField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Username"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel.cgColor
        return field
    }()
    
    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        field.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        field.placeholder = "Password"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel.cgColor
        return field
    }()
    
    private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Create account", for: .normal)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        button.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        createAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCreateAccountButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        emailField.delegate = self
        usernameField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self
        
        addSubviews()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    private func addSubviews() {
        view.addSubview(emailField)
        view.addSubview(usernameField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(createAccountButton)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        emailField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top + 100, width: view.width-40, height: 52)
        usernameField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: emailField.bottom + 10, width: view.width-40, height: 52)
        passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: usernameField.bottom + 10, width: view.width-40, height: 52)
        createAccountButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: passwordField.bottom + 10, width: view.width-40, height: 52)
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapCreateAccountButton() {
        print("creating account")
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        usernameField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        guard let userEmail = emailField.text, !userEmail.isEmpty, let userUsername = usernameField.text, !userUsername.isEmpty, let userPassword = passwordField.text, !userPassword.isEmpty, userPassword.count >= 8 else {
            return
        }
        
        // check if the email and username are available
        AuthManager.shared.emailUsernameAvailable(email: userEmail, username: userUsername) { areAvailable in
            if areAvailable {
                print("username and email are available")
            } else {
                print("username and email are NOT available")
            }
        }
    }

}

extension SignupViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == emailField {
            usernameField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == usernameField {
            passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == passwordField {
            didTapCreateAccountButton()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

And they are laid out like this:
[fresh view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jurho.png)

In the simulator, when I click on the password textField, the textField turns yellow and displays "Strong Password" while also hiding the entered text:.
[text typed into password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivs58.png)

However, I also realized that if I click on the password textField before both the email and username textField, the textField behaves as expected:
[text typed into password field before others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op9Af.png)

I've read other posts saying that XCode infers that the purpose of your view might be registration from the filenames and variable names, which could be causing the error, but I have not been able to find a fix for this specific case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First impression which I have is that you have a logic in your view controller which have side effects. Past you controller code.

The additional "password" label which covers your textfield content is expected behavior due to the option which you active and is called Password AutoFill.

To activate fully this function you have to enable App’s Associated Domains.

If it's impossible then just set textContentType to .password and set isSecureTextEntry to true.